# Why use encodeURIComponent() when writing json to a cookie

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, encoding

In particular, when saving a JSON to the cookie is it safe to just save the raw value?

The reason I dopn't want to encode is because the json has small values and keys but a complex structure, so encoding, replacing all the ", : and {}, greatly increases the string length

Answer (score 3):

if your values contain "JSON characters" (e.g. comma, quotes, [] etc) then you should probably use encodeURIComponent so these get escaped and don't break your code when reading the values back.

Comment: But the initial cookie written by the server side code is unescaped and doesn't break anything

Answer (score 2):

If you can't be certain that your JSON will not include reserved characters such as `;` then you will want to perform escaping on any strings being stored as a cookie. [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) covers special characters that are not allowed in the cookie-name or cookie-value.

If you are encoding static content you control, then this escaping may be unnecessary. If you are encoding dynamic content such as encoding user generated content, you probably need escaping.

MDN recommends using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie#:%7E:text=The%20cookie%20value%20string%20can%20use%20encodeURIComponent()%20to%20ensure%20that%20the%20string%20does%20not%20contain%20any%20commas%2C%20semicolons%2C%20or%20whitespace%20(which%20are%20disallowed%20in%20cookie%20values)) to escape any disallowed characters.

You can pull in a library such as [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) to handle this for you, but if your server is written in another language you will need to ensure it uses a library or language utilities to *encodeURIComponent* when setting cookies and to *decodeURIComponent* when reading cookies.

`JSON.stringify` is not sufficient as illustrated by this trivial example:

```
const bio = JSON.stringify({ "description": "foo; bar; baz" });
document.cookie = `bio=${stringified}`;

// Notice that the content after the first `;` is dropped.
// Attempting to JSON.parse this later will fail.
console.log(document.cookie) // bio={\"description\":\"foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your JSON object to a string using the JSON.stringify() method then save it in a cookie.

Note that cookies have a 4000 character limit.

If your Json string is valid there should be no need to encode it.

e.g.

`JSON.stringify({a:'foo"bar"',bar:69});`
=> `'{"a":"foo\"bar\"","bar":69}'` valid json stings are escaped.

Comment: I'm already doing this (to be pedantic, a json is technically the name of the string returned by JSON.stringify()) - the question is whether a json is safe to write as a cookie without escaping special characters

Comment: JSON.stringify automatically escapes characters as needed. how can you have a valid json string without it being escaped in the first place?

Comment: I think you may be getting escaped ("\"") and encoded ("%22") confused

Comment: encodeURIComponent replaces characters that are not valid as part of a uri, e.g. " gets changed to %22. I'm asking if this is necessary

Comment: Well, in the question it's clear I mean encode, so just to clarify further I mean "encode" not "escape"

Comment: In that case why does jQuery.cookie use the encodeURIComponent() function?

Comment: herostwist & @whererhys: encodeURIComponent will encode characters that don't need to be encoded, true. But it will also encode characters that do need to encoded, e.g. semicolons (possibly other characters, like space, can also be problematic in cookies). Since you have to decode on the server in case the value contained semicolons anyway, and it's a native function, it's the obvious choice.

Comment: This is bad advice unless you are 100% sure that your JSON object will never contain semicolons. Using encodeURIComponent() is much safer...

Answer (score 1):

This is documented very well on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

> To avoid unexpected requests to the server, you should call *encodeURIComponent* on **any user-entered parameters that will be passed as part of a URI**. For example, a user could type "Thyme &time=again" for a variable comment. Not using *encodeURIComponent* on this variable will give comment=Thyme%20&time=again. Note that the ampersand and the equal sign mark a new key and value pair. So instead of having a POST comment key equal to "Thyme &time=again", you have two POST keys, one equal to "Thyme " and another (time) equal to again.

Comment: The question is asking about cookies, not urls.

Answer (score 0):

[Cookie: name=value; name2=value2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Spaces are part of the cookie separation in the HTTP Cookie header. Raw spaces in cookie values could thus confuse the server.